# htaccess redirect root to www

Tags: .htaccess, dns, root

This question seems to be asked a lot before, but I'll ask it again, because it doesn't seem specific for my problem:

I want the domain.com, to be directed to www.domain.com
So I use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It just doesn't seem to work.

Now I'm hoping and thinking the problem is with my hoster, but they are not particularly responsive. When I go to the root domain I get a server error 500. When I contacted them they said I had to use a .htaccess file, but I think the problem is the HOSTS file, which does actually point to the right location (the root domain A-record points to the right IP, and the www. points to the root domain, so I'm thouroughly confused...)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this at the top. The extension of index file is dependant on your programming language.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```